# Accessing device SMS in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to create a flutter app that reads the device SMS and stores them in a list. for this, I am using this library:https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/sms/latest/

but the code provided in the documentation throws the following errors:

only static members can be accessed in initializers.dart(implicit_this_reference_in_initializer)
A value of type `Future<List<SmsMessage>>` can't be assigned to a variable of type `List<SmsMessage>.dart(invalid_assignment)`

Inorder to avoid this error I have tried adding List to Future> type annotation but first error still remains

Can someone provide me a proper way of doing this? Also if there is a better way of doing this? I am pretty new to flutter so I would request you to try to keep the explanations simple.

Thanks in advance.

This is the code in the documentation:

```
 SmsQuery query = SmsQuery();
 List<SmsMessage> messages = query.getAllSms;
```

Comment: Where are you calling the function? What type of List are you creating when you make the `messages` list? It seems like it should be `List<SmsMessage> messages = await query.getAllSms;` which would imply that you have not given your list a type.

Comment: @R.Duggan thank you for your reply, I have tried calling the function in main function as well as the in a  statelesswidget but it works in neither of them, also adding await requires the main function to be marked as async which is not in the docs, after I mark the main function as async the app fails to start.